# List assignment using slice-Anomalous behaviour

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-3.5

```
>>> b=[1,11,11,13]  
>>> b[5:3:-1]=13,14  
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#86>", line 1, in <module>
b[5:3:-1]=13,14
ValueError: attempt to assign sequence of size 2 to extended slice of size 0
>>> b[4:6]=13,14
>>> b
[1, 11, 11, 13, 13, 14]
```

What is the reason behind the above piece of code working the way it is?
Though both slices refer to the same indices, when -1 is used as the step value, it fails to yield the intended result.

Comment: @Zero Piraeus I don't quite understand why consistency is relevant here. Can't Python check if the assignment(extended slice) is feasible and then act upon it instead of banning all such cases? As you can see in the example given in my question, there are cases where the list can be lengthened and remain perfect without the "Frankenstein-like" qualities.

Comment: *Python* can, yes. The problem with inconsistency is the potential it has to trip up the *programmer*. As mentioned in the linked answer, there are cases where a stride greater than 1 can be sensibly interpreted, but a feature which either works or doesn't based on complex rules is surprising, and therefore badly designed.